# PHP dynamic array name with loop

Tags: php, arrays

I need to get values of array through a loop with dynamic vars.
I can't understand why the "echo" doesn’t display any result for "$TAB['b']". 
Do you know why ?

The test with error message : https://3v4l.org/Fp3GT

```
$TAB_a = "aaaaa";
$TAB['b'] = "bbbbb"; 
$TAB['b']['c'] = "ccccc"; 


$TAB_paths = ["_a", "['b']", "['b']['c']"];

foreach ($TAB_paths as $key => $value) {
    echo "\n\n\${'TAB'.$value} : "; print_r(${'TAB'.$value});
    }
```

Comment: Please post Error ?

Comment: Doesn't work _in what way_?  What is the current result?  What is the expected result?

Comment: @RonakDhoot done

Comment: @PatrickQ Is that more clear ?

Comment: What it boils down to is that that's just not how arrays work. The array access characters aren't actually part of the variable name, if that makes sense. So if you have an array `$TAB = array('b' => 'something');`, the variable name is `$TAB`. When you do `${'TAB'.$value}`, you're looking for a variable that's actually named `$TAB['b']`, which you don't have.

Comment: @PatrickQ Thanks for your clear answer. Then do you no a way to achieve my need ? ==> I need to store indexes of an associative array (A) in another array (B). Then loop through (B) to get values in (A).

Comment: Store just the indexes, not the access characters.  So instead of storing "['b']", just store "b".  Then you do `$A[$value]`  (where `$value` is an individual entry value from the `$B` array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are treating the array access characters as if they are part of the variable name.  They are not.

So if you have an array `$TAB = array('b' => 'something');`, the variable name is `$TAB`. When you do `${'TAB'.$value}`, you're looking for a variable that's actually named `$TAB['b']`, which you don't have.

Since you say that you just want to be able to access array indexes dynamically based on the values in another array, you just put the indexes alone (without the array access characters) in the other array.

```
$TAB['b'] = 'bbbbbb';
$TAB['c'] = 'cccccc';

$TAB_paths = array('b', 'c');

foreach ($TAB_paths as $key => $value) {
    echo "\n\n".'$TAB['."'$value'".'] : ' . $TAB[$value];
}
```

Output:

> $TAB['b'] : bbbbbb
>
> $TAB['c'] : cccccc

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9ceef4c0d38ce4bb40d0e96566c7308aab19caf1)

Comment: Ok thank you, the main reason is now perfectly clear. In fact, my need is a little bit more complicated. I just added $TAB['b']['c'] = "ccccc"; In this case, Does your solution work ? (my impression is no)

Comment: My answer works for the problem as presented.  If you have another problem, you should post another question.  You should also try to accurately describe your problem in detail _as it actually exists_.  Being vague about what you're actually trying to accomplish just creates more work and confusion for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you're trying to do, although you need to include `$TAB_all` in `$TAB_paths`:

```
$TAB_paths = [$TAB_all['a'], $TAB_all['aside']['nav']];
```

**Result**:

```
${TAB_all.aaaaa} : ${TAB_all.bbbbb} :
```

Comment: Thanks but no. I need to understand why nothing is display for $TAB['b']. I just modified the code to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Not certain what you're needing.  My guess you need to merge two arrays into one.  Easiest solution is to use the array_merge function.

```
$TAB_paths = array_merge($TAB_a1, $TAB_a2);
```

Comment: Thanks but no. I need to understand why nothing is display for $TAB['b']. I just modified the code to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the variable first

```
foreach ($TAB_all as $key => $value) {
   ${"TAB_all" . $key} = $value;   
}
```

Now Explore the result:

```
foreach ($TAB_all as $key => $value) {
        print_r(${"TAB_all" . $key});   
}
```

Comment: Thanks but no. I need to understand why nothing is display for $TAB['b']. I just modified the code to be more clear.